# 'UserForm' object has no attribute 'Cleaned_data'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

So I just created a form and keep getting this error, why? I correctly use the Cleaned_data after I checked if the form is valid, right?

This is my forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
username = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

This is my views.py:

```
class UserFormView(View):
form_class = UserForm
template_name = 'Home/index.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        username = form.Cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.Cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('Home:Dashboard')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^register$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),]
```

and the form location:

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<ul class="contactList">
    <li id="username1" class="contact">{{ form.username }}</li>
    <li id="email1" class="contact">{{ form.email }}</li>
    <li id="password1" class="contact">{{ form.password }}</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

There are other topics about this issue but I could not get any help out of them, as most people didn't include the if form.is_valid(), but in my case I do.

Comment: `cleaned_data` should be lowercase

Comment: @Sayse Appriciate your reply. Changed both of them to lowercases, still getting the same error..

Comment: Please include the full stack trace

Comment: Please include the error message.  It'd be good to align properly with 4 spaces.  Try debugging with pdb or ipdb and let us know what you see there.

Answer (score 2):

Use `form.cleaned_data.get('username')` instead of `form.Cleaned_data`

**Edit**
Use `FormView`

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
class UserFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'Home/index.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        ...
```

`get_form_class` returns the class of the form i.e `UserForm`. You need is a object of that class. The class does not have any attribute `cleaned_data`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed both form.Cleaned_data to form.cleaned_data.get('username/password'), still the same error.

Comment: Are you using `FormView` or `View` in view base class?

Comment: View, class UserFormView(View): in my views.py

Comment: Use `FormView` as base class and override `form_valid` method. Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/